# How do I create an array of objects the right way?

Tags: java, arrays, object

So I'm just starting to use objects in Java and I heard you can make an array of objects, but I'm having some problems with it.

```
public class Minesweeper {

    static int Turns;
    static boolean Won;
    static String Name;
    static int Winnings;
    public Minesweeper(boolean won, int turns,String pName,int score){
        Turns=turns;
        Won=won;
        Name=pName;
        Winnings=score;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inpt = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pl=0,again,respd;
        String ans;
        String pName;
        Minesweeper [] player= new Minesweeper[20];

        do{

        again=0;
        respd=0;

        System.out.println("What's your name?");
        pName=inpt.next();


        Won=false;
        Turns=0;    

        play(inpt);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Play Again?");

        ans = inpt.next();
        if(ans.charAt(0)=='y'||ans.charAt(0)=='Y'){
            again=1;
        }
        else{
            again=0;
        }

        player[pl]= new Minesweeper(Won,Turns,pName,Winnings);
        pl++;

        }while(again==1);

        System.out.println("Won?:\tName:\tTurns:\t:Score:");
        for(int i=0;i<pl;i++){
            System.out.println(player[i].Won+"\t"+player[i].Name+"\t"+player[i].Turns+"\t"+player[i].Winnings);
        }

    }
```

It just outputs the last player's score repeatedly (because of the loop), I want it to print every player that has played the game.

What are the lines do I have to change

The whole code
https://pastebin.com/hX1kEYcQ

Comment: `static` variables belong to classes - in other words, they are not changed across instances of a class. Read up on the `static` context in java. So: if you want different players to have different `turns` for example, `turns` can't be static.

Comment: Take all the `static` modifiers away from the Minesweeper class. Then, all the places you used those variables in main (a `static` context), instead use `player[pl].Won` or whichever variable you need to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields you intend to store the data for each player are `static`. This contradicts their intended use.

If you have 5 instances of your class, `static int Turns;` makes the field exist only once. Removing `static` gives every instance a separate field, which is what you need.

(BTW, field names in Java usually start with lower case, so better use `turns` instead of `Turns`.)

If you turn

```
static int Turns;
static boolean Won;
static String Name;
static int Winnings;
```

into

```
int turns;
boolean won;
String name;
int winnings;
```

you'll see that your main loop doesn't work any longer.

Thus, you have to add local variables in your `main()`:

```
int turns = 0;
boolean won = false;
String name;
int winnings;
```

The `won` and `turns` values have to be obtained somehow as well in a clean way, as well as `winnings`. (Maybe you want to make them a separate class `GameResult` which is returned by `play()`.)

Then you can do

```
    player[pl]= new Minesweeper(won,turns,pName,winnings);
```

(BTW, the name should maybe put first, but that's a matter of style.)

Comment: Removing them creates an error: "cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: This is because you're using the variables directly in the static `main` method. You'll need to access them from the object. So you'll need to get access to the Minesweeper object. If your object is named `m`, you'll call `m.turns` or `m.getTurns()` if you make it private and expose a public getter method

Comment: _"The won and turns values have to be obtained somehow as well in a clean way, as well as winnings. (Maybe you want to make them a separate class GameResult which is returned by play().)"_

Know a good way on how to do it?

Comment: @YourAlly Well, I don't know your `play()` method. But it should return all the data it has and you need encapsulated in a separate object, or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size ahead of time, I'd use a List instead of array:

`List<Minesweeper> minesweeperList = new ArrayList<>();`

Then, you can just:

`minesweeperList.add(new Minesweeper(Won,Turns,pName,Winnings));`

Then:

```
for(Minesweeper m : minesweeperList) {
    ...
}
```

Static values in Java mean there is only 1 value shared by *all objects in your program*. The way you have it written all Minesweeper objects share the same information for each static var. Change them to "instance" variables by removing the "static" keyword:

```
public class Minesweeper {

    int Turns;
    boolean Won;
    String Name;
    int Winnings;
    public Minesweeper(boolean won, int turns,String pName,int score){
        Turns=turns;
        Won=won;
        Name=pName;
        Winnings=score;

    }
```

Comment: I'd also address that the OP's problem *"it just outputs the last player's score repeatedly"* is caused by the `static` context.